# Is the use of 'would have' in this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: tense

**I wish this day would have never come.**

Shouldn't 'had' be simply used in place  'would have' here, since, 'would have' is used in reference to the past, and furthermore, when talking about a wish, past perfect tense is used ?

Comment: "had never come" would be the obvious tense,  but what is the context?  What is the source?

Comment: My guess it is Nadal's  (an able but non-native speaker of English) Twitter post (a casual form of writing) about the retirement of Federer.  It was described in the English press as "emotional" (suggesting that grammatical accuracy isn't so important here).

Comment: Yes, it's syntactically valid. But many people won't like it much - especially Brits, who very rarely use non-contracted ***would*** in contexts like *If I **would** have known you were coming, I'd have baked a cake*. Also note that Brits in particular are likely to "unpack" that ***'d*** as ***had***, so they're much more likely to say *If I **had** have lost you, I don't know what I'd do* (where most Americans don't mind *If I **would have** lost you...*).

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wish+it+would+never+have%22) are a couple of dozen written instances of *[I] [wish it would never have](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wish+it+would+never+have%22) [happened]*. But I doubt *any* of them will be from *British* authors (we'd always opt for contracted [***I wish it'd never happened***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+wish+it%27d+never+happened%22) to avoid ***would***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "If I had have lost you" ??? Don't you mean "If I had lost you"?

Comment: @ColinFine: No. I definitely mean *If **I'd have** lost you*, where I (and a not insignificant number of my fellow Anglophones! :) "unpack"  ***I'd*** as ***I had***. But as seems clear from ["If I would have lost you" vs "If I had lost you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you) others (Americans in particular) don't share my aversion to full-blown ***would*** in that context. To me, that just sounds like a German speaking English! :)

Comment: To me, _I had have lost you_ is simply ungrammatical, and I would be surprised to encounter it (the iWeb corpus has just 7 instances of "had have lost") . _I would have lost you_ is grammatical: I would not use it after "if", but I am aware that others do. (5011 instances in iWeb, and desultory bowsing suggests that very few of them are within an "if" clause). I agree that the former probably arise from a mistaken unpacking of "I'd".

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly valid:

> I wish this day would have never come.

> I wish this day had never come.

There is a subtle difference between the two. The first implies that there was a chance it might not have come, while the second example doesn't really suggest that.

According to the comments, the second example is preferred (unless you want to suggest that this day might not have ever come).

Comment: Not sure about all my compatriots, but (as a Brit?) I don't really have a problem with [***I wish it'd never have come to this***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wish+it%27d+never+have+come%22) It's specifically *uncontracted "**would**"* that most Brits avoid.

Comment: That American 'would have' really grinds [many peoples'](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/) gears, including a lot of Americans.